# Powershell get excel formula result

Tags: excel, powershell, com

i'm using excel COM object in a powershell script and i would like to insert a formula in a cell (maybe format the cell as it can be Text format instead of General), then get the formula result and insert this result (as text) in another cell.

My problem is that i can't reformat the cell back to general so i only get the formula as plain text.

What i have tried so far :

```
$elecFormula1 = "=...Some valid and tested formula"
$sheetDest.Cells.Item($dummyCellX, $dummyCellY).NumberFormat = "General" # This throws an error
$sheetDest.Cells.Item($dummyCellX, $dummyCellY).Formula = $elecFormula1
$key = "" + $sheetDest.Cells.Item($dummyCellX, $dummyCellY).Value2
$sheetDest.Cells.Item($i, 2) = $key
```

Comment: For now, as a temporary solution i put my formula cells far away at a distance where there should not be any formatting but this is not an ideal solution (especially if someone format the entire sheet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

$excel               = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.Visible       = $True
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $False 

$workbook            = $excel.Workbooks.Open( "C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\test.xlsx", [System.Type]::Missing, $false ) 

$worksheet = $workbook.WorkSheets.item(1)
[void]$worksheet.activate()

$worksheet.Range("A1").NumberFormat = ""
$worksheet.Range("A1").NumberFormat = $worksheet.Range("A1").NumberFormatLocal # "General" or "Standard"
$worksheet.Range("A1").Formula = "=1+1"

$result = $worksheet.Range("A1").value2

$result

[void]$workbook.Close( $false ) 
[void]$excel.Quit() 

[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel) | Out-Null
```

Comment: So the solution is that the "General" format can be "Standard" depending on the locals ? Is there a mean to force one local ? I already had such problem with formulas separators ("," or ";")

Comment: Formulas always have to been set in english language format! E. g. sverweis => vlookup. For some reasons cell format is different, some times "General", some time "Standard". Clear format first and then check with NumberFormatLocal the right term, "General" or "Standard"

Answer (score 0):

Say I have an Excel file with 'X' filled in at A1:A5 and want to test how much times it occurs. If I do the following, I will return the formula:

```
$excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application 
$excel.visible = $True
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add()
$sheetDest = $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
$sheetDest.Name = "Test for StackOverflow"
$row = 0
$column = 1
for($i = 0; $i -le 4; $i++){
    $row++
    $sheetDest.Cells.Item($row,$column) = "X"
}
$formula = '=COUNTIF(A1:A5,"X")'
$sheetDest.Cells.Item(6,1) = $formula
$fieldValue = $sheetDest.Cells.Item(6,1).value2
$formula = $sheetDest.Cells.Item(6,1).Formula
Write-Host "Value is $fieldValue"
Write-Host "Formula is $formula"
```

It will write the formula and the value for you! The value can then be set somewhere else by using:

```
$sheetDest.Cells.Item($someRow,$someColumn) = $fieldValue
```

You can run this exact code to test it, but if I am misunderstanding your question, please elaborate.

Comment: Sorry if i wasn't clear, english is not my natal language. My problem was more with cells format as i format most of the sheet to text but i want to reformat some specific cells to enter formulas. However i get an error when i try to set the "General" format.
See @f6a4 answer which i think is what i searched